# TensorFlow: Why does tf.one_hot give the best performance on tf.uint8 dtypes?

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow, computer-vision, deep-learning

I am rather puzzled by how there is a huge variance (5% difference in accuracy) in the performance of the same model (keeping all other factors the same), when I simply place the conversion of my labels dtype (tf.uint8) after using `tf.one_hot`, meaning to say the `tf.one_hot` function processes uint8 integers instead.

For example

```
...

labels = tf.cast(labels, tf.int64)
labels = tf.one_hot(labels, num_classes=12)
```

In comparison to

```
...
labels = tf.one_hot(labels, num_classes=12)
labels = tf.cast(labels, tf.int64)
```

the latter has better performance.

Is there a preferred dtype when using `tf.one_hot`?

Comment: What is labels at ...

Comment: this does not make any sense. Are you sure this is not a random fluctuation?

Comment: Yes indeed I'm quite puzzled by this either. I tested the model thrice, unless all three times the model fluctuated positively, which is still possible. Note that one very weird effect I've tried is to convert uint8 to float32 before converting to int32, and my predictions became incoherent. That's why I'm wondering if changing dtypes have certain mutations not known yet.

Comment: This could very well happen.  It would be very telling if you posted your loss function along with the dtype of the output **logits** or output **labels** (whichever is used in the loss function).